# Im working on a calculator app with some complex formulas

Tags: variables, initialization, calculator

The Calculator code:

```
@IBAction func Calc(sender: UIButton) {
    var a = Int(curppm.text!)
    var b = Int(tarppm.text!)
    var c = Int(vol.text!)
}
```

I'm receiving an error showing:

```
initialization of variable (a,b,c) was never used.
```

This is my first app, kind of stuck. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: First of all, you assigned value to var a,b,c but never make use of any. For instance, after you assigned a = 2, you need to make use of a to do something such as a = a + 1 in the following code. In your question, i did not see any further appearance as a, b, c , being used.

Comment: The second one is an advice, It is better to paste what you have done or more related codes just to let us know better how to adjust your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may solve your problem by making use of the var a,b,c.

For your example,

```
@IBAction func Calc(sender: UIButton) {
    var a = Int(curppm.text!)
    var b = Int(tarppm.text!)
    var c = Int(vol.text!)
    a = b + c //input any logic you want here making use of a,b,c
}
```

Just input your logic in the line of a = b + c

But to be honest, the scope of your variable is a problem maybe, you should probably declare it outside of the function i guess. I am not familiar of swift but most of the programming language, var only live in the function and will get destroyed after function execution.